# Como redimensionar uma WebPart de uma app dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, app, sharepoint

Eu criei uma App para Sharepoint e dentro do projeto adicionei uma Webpart.

Queria que essa Webpart crescesse ou diminuísse dinamicamente baseada no seu conteúdo.

Tentei adicionar alguns códigos de fora da app, mas esbarrei em questões de segurança, então queria fazer isso de dentro da propria app através de javascript. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei essa solução Cross-domain que permite a comunicação do iframe da App com o documento pai.

O javascript fica assim:

```
window.Communica = window.Communica || {};

Communica.Part = {
    senderId: '',

    init: function () {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var param = params[i].split("=");
            if (param[0].toLowerCase() == "senderid")
                this.senderId = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
        }


        this.adjustSize();
    },

    adjustSize: function () {
        var step = 30,
            newHeight,
            contentHeight = $('#userDataContent').height(),
            resizeMessage = '<message senderId={Sender_ID}>resize({Width}, {Height})</message>';

        newHeight = contentHeight + 150;

        resizeMessage = resizeMessage.replace("{Sender_ID}", this.senderId);
        resizeMessage = resizeMessage.replace("{Height}", newHeight);
        resizeMessage = resizeMessage.replace("{Width}", "100%");

        window.parent.postMessage(resizeMessage, "*");
    }
};
```

Quando clico em alguma parte do iframe que altera o seu conteúdo via função javascript eu adicionei ao final dessa função a chamada:

```
Communica.Part.init();
```

O #userDataContent poderia ser o body do iframe por exemplo, caso ele reflita o conteudo do iframe.